# Why Custom ArrayAdapter of my android application is not showing image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-arrayadapter, out-of-memory

I have made an android application where image will save to local database when the network is unavailable. I am keeping image uri inside database table and retrieving image from image uri and showing that image on `imageView` of a `listView`  using Custom array adapter. When I am running my application with emulator, it is working well. However while using an android mobile phone it showing *Forced Close error*.

The error log is given below:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:504)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:675)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:525)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:309)
at com.freedom.net.Syncho2$NoteListAdapter.getView(Syncho2.java:219)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1519)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1749)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:731)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1602)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1349)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1263)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1137)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1051)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1263)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1137)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1051)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1162)
```

MY Custom adapter is given below:

```
public class NoteListAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<ImageFromDB> {
Context c;

ArrayList<ImageFromDB> image = null;
ArrayList<String> uriImage = null;
ArrayList<Integer> ID = null;

private AllId allid = null;
DBAdapter db = null;

WatchListAllEntity watchListAllEntity=null;
int flagVariable=1;
private ArrayList<ImageFromDB> items;

public NoteListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<ImageFromDB> items) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    Log.e("sf","123");
    this.items = items;
    c=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final int myPosition = position;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitempict2, null);
    }
    ImageFromDB re = items.get(position);
    Log.e("re", re+"");
    if (re != null) {
        ImageView tt = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageviewproduct);
        String imageUri = re.getImageuri();
        Log.e("imageUri", imageUri+"");
        tt.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));

        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkboxproduct);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    if(flagVariable==1)
                    {
                        String ImUri = items.get(myPosition).getImageuri();
                        allid.setImageUri(ImUri);
                        allid.setId(items.get(myPosition).getId());
                        flagVariable++;
                        Log.e("flagVariable  : " , flagVariable+"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        //Toast.makeText(Syncho2.this,"正しく選んでください。",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    flagVariable=1;
                    Log.e("flagVariable  : " , flagVariable+"");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

I am calling this *Adapter* from a activity like this:

```
noteListAdapter = new NoteListAdapter(this, R.layout.listitempict, image);
```

I noticed from debug, the *Adapter* is being called **six times** when the image is only **two** . **Five times** it's returning a *view* but on the **sixth time** it is showing that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution . I thing everybody should know about memory management of android application. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk .  When I am trying to show image Uri directly on ImageView then the problem is creating . I thing everybody  should avoid code like this ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri)) . Instead of that, try to load bitmap or drawable on imageview.

Answer (score 2):

Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
and you'll be able to load your image without any error!

Comment: i'm sure that compressing the bitmap will not fully help in this case - the app will forceclose not on the sixs' time but on the 16s' (for exmaple) =)

Comment: It's not about the compressing, it's about loading a scaled down version of the image. On the scree you don't need to display a 8Mp image. Just load the image scaled down to your screen size.

Comment: "I noticed from debug ,the Adapter is calling six times when the image is only two"  -  as you see even if he make this images smaller the problem is not only in scaled image, it will help only not to fall on the sixs' step - but it will forceclose after some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        

        View row = convertView;
     // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        if (row == null) {  
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            row = li.inflate(R.layout.menucategory, null);          
            //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));         
        }
            // getCategoryItem          
            Category  category = (Category) getItem(position);
            // Get reference to ImageView
            categoryIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
            //categoryIcon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            categoryIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            categoryIcon.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            categoryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            //Set category name
            categoryName.setText(category.getCategoryName());           


            if(category.getCategoryPath() != null){             
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(category.getCategoryPath());
                    System.out.println("bitmap2::  "+ bitmap);
                    if(bitmap != null){
                     categoryIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }               
            }                              

        return row;
    }
```